# Can we run CakePHP shell script on browser?

Tags: cakephp

Can we run shell scripts made with CakePHP on Browser?

This script can work perfectly as a CakePHP console based program (app/vendors/shells/test.php). But is it possible to run it on browser somehow?

```
class TestShell extends Shell {
    function initialize() {
    }
    function main() {
        echo "Test";
    }  
}
```

The reason I am asking is, I have some Cron jobs (made in cakephp), and it would be so much time saving to be able to run and debug them on browser.

Thanks

Comment: The path and filename in `app/vendors/shells/test.php``is wrong for 2.x - You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should write a test case for it.
This way you can even see the mysql queries run.

place TestShellTest.php in \app\Test\Case\Console\Command\

```
App::uses('TestShell', 'Console/Command');

class TestShellTest extends CakeTestCase {

    public $Test;

    public function setUp() {
        $this->Test = new TestShell();
    }

    public function tearDown() {

    }

    public function testObject() {
        $this->assertIsA($this->Test, 'TestShell');

    }


    public function testRun() {
        $this->Test->main();
        //$this->assertEqual(...);
    }

}
```

this is 2.0 syntax (1.3 is slightly different)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this would really help.  i will write a test case. Thanks

Comment: App::uses('AppShell', 'Console/Command'); You need to add 'AppShell' also.

Comment: No, you don't. The actual class takes care of that. You only include the direct requirements, not the indirect ones!

Comment: Just as mark pointed out, you don't need to include the AppShell here but it should be included in the included file. So in this case, TestShell should have App::uses('AppShell', 'Console/Command');